# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException : Required Long parameter 'userId' is not present"

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, post

I am getting an exception while posting a call to Spring controller

Exception is:

```
 org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException : Required Long parameter 'userId' is not present"
```

My Javascript file is:

```
$scope.removeUser = function(user){
        var userId = JSON.stringify(user);
        $http.post('/portal/settings/user/deletecustomeruser', userId).success(function(data){
                $scope.response = data;
            })
        }
    }
```

The Spring controller code is:

```
      @RequestMapping( value = "/user/deletecustomeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST , headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String deleteCustomerUser( @RequestParam (value = "userId") Long userId,
        HttpServletRequest request )
                throws Exception
                {
    String returnString = "";
    User user = userService.getUserById( userId );
```

When I put `(required = false)`, then the `userId` value became `null`. 
The JavaScript controller is clearly sending the `"userId"` in JSON format, but from the controller side there is some issue.

I checked almost all questions in stackoverflow, but the given solutions didn't help.

Comment: Can you show the JSON which is being posted. I think the JSON you are posting is not in proper format. you are sending only the value. You need to send it in key/value pair e.g. `{"userId":123}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are expecting userId as request parameter on server side, but you are sending userId as request body in your client http post request,

Change the client side to send userId as request parameter

```
 $http.post('/portal/settings/user/deletecustomeruser?userId='+userId)
```

Or Change server side to use userId as request body in the controller

```
myControllerMethod (@RequestBody String userId)
```

Comment: @RequestBody annotation doesn't have a value property

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping
    public List<PostCreateRequest> getAllPost(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer id){
          return postservice.getAllpost(id);
    }
```

this is my works.
`@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0")` here is really worked!